# Retrieving data from string(tags)

Tags: php, mysql, tags

The script fetches input from user and searches database field, named tags.

tags contains data for eg: hello, hey, how , happy, hell .. on single cell or you may say as a string.

i tried the query below, but it only works for hello and not for how , happy, hell..

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tws where tags='".$name."' or tags LIKE '".$name.",%' or tags LIKE
 ',%".$name.",%' or  tags LIKE '%,".$name."'";
```

Note: I thoroughly searched google and stack overflow before posting this question but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one percent-sign placed wrong (the third `LIKE`) and MySQL is quite strict: you have to include the spaces between your tags in the SQL:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tws where tags='".$name."' or tags LIKE '".$name.",%' 
       or tags LIKE '%, ".$name.",%' or  tags LIKE '%, ".$name."'";
```

should work (remove the space after how, so your data has a fixed format).

PS: Make sure you use `mysql(i)_real_escape_string` to escape the value `$name`

Consider using an extra table where you store your tags. e.g. `tws_tags`, with fields `tws_id` and `tag` and a query with a JOIN on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Could you suggest me a book so that i can get better at php and mysql?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. I've learned PHP about 10 years ago, so anything I used is very outdated now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tws` WHERE `tags` REGEXP (".$name.")";
```

Comment: i got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '".)"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Yes it did but it also gave some error anyways thanks, i really appreciate it i wish there was someone who could guide me in php mysql and even in web development.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM tws where tags='".$name."' or 
           tags LIKE '".$name."%' or tags LIKE
             '%".$name."%' or  tags LIKE '%".$name."'";
```

Here your query looks like below if name = ABC

```
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM tws where tags='ABC' or tags LIKE 'ABC,%' or tags LIKE
 ',ABC,%' or  tags LIKE '%,ABC'";
```

You can see that it is looking for ,ABC not only for ABC

Answer (score 0):

You should omit the commas in your query like this:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `tws` WHERE `tags` RLIKE '%[[:<:]]$name[[:>:]]%'";
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are special markers in MySQL for word boundaries. Alse, in double quotes you can use variables without having to concatenate (`"blablabla $smth txt"` instead of `"blablabla " . $smth . " txt"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot friends. You all have so much knowledge i wish i had some and i would be helping other... anyways thanks a lot.